# Want to update ipa file in Itunesconnect for another account

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I recently sold some of my iOS apps to another person.

I transfer the apps to this buyer account, but now I want to update some apps for the person.

The buyer create a new user for me with Admin rights in his itunesconnect account, I get the login(Apple ID) and password and add it to Xcode 8, you can see it in the image below.

[image: New user added to Xcode]

I let Xcode generate automatically, but when I select the "Team" on Xcode using the new user that I added in Xcode, Xcode generate an error. The error is:

---

Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "com.uaialternativa.superpixelworld" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

No profiles for 'com.uaialternativa.superpixelworld' were found

### Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.uaialternativa.superpixelworld'.

You can see the error in the image below

[image: Error generated in Xcode 8]

What I can do to correct this error, because I try to access the site "https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome", but for this new user doesn't have an option to create certificates.

How I can correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purchase/enroll for Apple developer account
[Apple-Link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

As of today Apple says -

> The Apple Developer Program annual fee is 99 USD and the Apple
>   Developer Enterprise Program annual fee is 299 USD, in local currency
>   where available. Prices may vary by region and are listed in local
>   currency during the enrollment process.

purchase & activation by [Apple-doc](https://developer.apple.com/support/purchase-activation/)

Comment: You need to go for enterprise account

Comment: Thanks @Jack for your answer. I already have an account that is enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, but I ask the buyer to create an new user for me using another account(that is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program). I just ask the buyer now to delete the old user and create a new user for me using my account associated with the Developer Program. it works now. Thanks! An enterprise account is not necessary

Comment: You are right, I can update the IPA file, but only using my certificates. Since the app is not in my account anymore, the Application Loader reject the app update. A Enterprise account is necessary to update the app in another developer account.

Comment: I do not believe that is the case.  An Enterprise account provides the ability to perform enterprise builds, which you can install on devices that don't need to be specifically included (by UDID) in an provisioning profile.  What you need to do is create a certificate on the buyer's account (make sure you get the private key for the cert), create a provisioning profile with that cert, and then build the app with that cert.